# DO.. WHILE.. with SWITCH menu

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, switch-statement

Here is a do..while loop with switch menu..

I am trying to make the user be able to return to the menu which is

```
System.out.println("Options: (C)reate, (R)ead, (W)rite, (L)ist, (S)ave or (E)xit.        (*****)");
```

But after much trial and errors, I still cant get back to the main menu after choosing C, R, W, L or S.

Below is a short snippet of the codes..

```
do {
    System.out.println("Options: (C)reate, (R)ead, (W)rite, (L)ist, (S)ave or (E)xit.   
    (*****)");
    Scanner switchC = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your choice: ");
    choice = switchC.next().charAt(0);

    switch (Character.toUpperCase(choice)) {
        case 'C':
    System.out.println("C");
            break;
        case 'R':
            break;
        case 'W':
            break;
        case 'L':
            break;
        case 'S':
            break;
        case 'E':
            System.exit(1);
        default:
            System.out.println("Options: (C)reate, (R)ead, (W)rite, (L)ist, (S)ave or (E)xit.        (*****)");
        } 
} while(choice!='E');
```

Comment: You should use a single `Scanner` instead of creating one every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
do{

}
while(Character.toUpperCase(choice) !='E')
```

Comment: Just tried.. can't work.. still exiting the program right away

Comment: @John If you use this solution, you **need** to remove `System.exit(1);` from the E case.